# Replace portion of string

Tags: regex, r

I want to replace anything that has `issue # 000...` or `issue #000...` (note space between digits and pound sign) with an href url based on the digits part of that string.  The `...` represents any number of digits.

**## Here is a MWE string:**

```
News <- readLines(n=5)
CHANGES

* Fixed bug see GitHub issue #12

* Fixed bug see GitHub issue # 111. (John Doe)

News
```

**## Here are the pieces of the href url**

```
## Roots
roota <- "<a href=\"https://github.com/trinker/qdap/issues/"
rootb <- "\">"
rootc <- "</a>"
```

**## Here's the desired output**

```
c("CHANGES",                                       
    "",                                              
    "* Fixed bug see GitHub <a href=\"https://github.com/trinker/qdap/issues/12\">issue #12</a>" ,             
    "",                                              
    "* Fixed bug see GitHub <a href=\"https://github.com/trinker/qdap/issues/111\">issue #111</a>. (John Doe)"
)
```

**## Here's my initial attempt at extracting the pieces**

```
gsub("(.)(issue)(.[#])(\\s*)([0-9]+)", "\\1", News)
```

**## Grabbing the digits I could almost paste them together with**

```
paste(roota, DIGIT_GRABBED, rootb, "issue #, DIGIT_GRABBED, rootc)
```

****I marked this with a regex tag but note that R regex is a particular breed and you should be familiar with R if you answer.***

Comment: @Josh yeah, fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use:

```
gsub(pattern="issue *# *([0-9]+)", replacement="<a href=\"https://github.com/trinker/qdap/issues/\\1\">issue #\\1</a>", x=News)
```

Comment: Perfect and easier than what I was trying.  I'll check as soon as 10 mins is up.